# How to get Local country from the language?

Tags: java, localization, internationalization

How to find `country` from its `Locale-language` ?

e.g; if I set the local `language` to `en` then I expect to get `US` as country.

```
Locale locale = new Locale("en");
locale.getCountry() // returns null
```

The issue is that I only have the country code such as: `fr,de,en` and now I just want to find the right country locale from these codes.

Answer (score 4):

`en` is English. `en_US` is US English. `en_GB` is, I think, UK English. Presumably using en_US would do what you want. There's a list of all the supported locales here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/locales-137662.html

You can't get the country from "en" because as you can see, multiple countries may share a language. Which one would you pick?

Comment: tnx, the prolem is that I only have the country code such as: `fr,de,en` and now I just want to find the right country locale from these codes. BTW it doesn't working with `en_US` as well.

Comment: @stsd Ah, I got the format wrong. If you read the javadoc, you would see that there's a two-parameter constructor for Locale. Those are not country codes. They are language codes. As I said, each language can be spoken in multiple countries.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to get all avaialble locales:

```
Locale[] locales = Locale.getAvailableLocales();
```

then insert them into a `HashMap` and define the `language` as `key`. Now its possible to search for the country via the language key.

Answer (score 1):

[Apache Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) has a method for that:
[`LocaleUtils#countriesByLanguage(String)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/LocaleUtils.html#countriesByLanguage(java.lang.String))

You can call getCountry() on each of the returned `Locale`s to get the country code. As Eric already pointed out, for many languages there are several countries.